# How to handle Dynamic session id coming as cookie in a web application?

Tags: performance, cookies, jmeter, performance-testing

in jmeter,While recording to a SAP based successfactor application in login i am seeing session id is passing as cookie that changes with every itteration how we can handle this?

I tried capturing this dynamic cookie from regular expression extractor but we are not able to capture anything from request body. I also tried jsr223 to extract but i am not able to extract....please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

JMeter automatically handles cookies given you add a [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your test plan.

If you need to use some cookie's value somewhere else you can play the next trick:

1. Add the [following line](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#miscellaneous) to *user.properties* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

   ```
   CookieManager.save.cookies=true
   ```
2. Restart JMeter
3. Once done you should be able to access the cookies which are stored in the HTTP Cookie Manager as `${COOKIE_your-cookie-name-here}`

More information: [HTTP Cookie Manager Advanced Usage - A Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-cookie-manager)